# Hand rotation and elbow rotation

Tags: rotational-dynamics

I have wondered that if we rotate our hand by any degree then the angle made by elbow is always less then the angle made by the hand???  Can any one tell me why so??

Comment: This question is more related to biology than physics.

Comment: Anatomy mechanics: because a human arm is not a solid cylinder but made of 2 bones which realize a kind of torsion-able cylinder on a limited angular interval.

Comment: Actually this question is related to robotics and it has a strictly mechanical (and hence Physics) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hand rotation has one degree of freedom. That means the all parts of the arm from the elbow down move "in unison". Not the same amount, but by a proportional amount. This rotation comes from the *Radius* and the *Ulna* twisting against each other ([wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arm#/media/File:Human_arm_bones_diagram.svg)).

You notice that your elbow never rotates. Try to grab your elbow and twist it and you will notice this. All the rotation is acquired along the arm after the elbow. Notice also the after the wrist base, you cannot rotate any more.

So to answer your question, there is only one "joint" to produce rotation and that is only the relative motion of the wrist to the elbow.